# How can I get any element from Set<string> with type string|undefined?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript, how can I get any element from Set with type `string|undefined` ?

```js
const set1 = new Set<string>();
set1.add('a');
const set2 = new Set<string>();

// I want to get any element of set with type string or undefined if set is empty
const e1 = set1.values().next(); // e1 is not type of string|undefined 
// e1 is type: IteratorResult<T, TReturn>
const e2 = set1.values().next().value; 
// compile error: Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
```

I want to get typesafe element which is `'a'` for `set1` and `undefined` for `set2`

how can I get a return type string|undefined?

Certainly, I can write some help function to achieve this. Is there some built-in api I can get this?

```js
function getAnyElement(set: Set<string>): string|undefined {
    let ans: string|undefined = undefined;
    for (const e of set) {
        ans = e;
        break;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: The "built-in API" for Typescript is really just the Javascript standard library. You can check the API documentation for `Set` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Comment: @kaya3 The issue isn't the API. It's the type returned by `set.values().next().value` being `any` despite it being a set of `string`. The issue is something about generators are the type of TReturn: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/32d2253e37e8a02a385a859c2d0b721c7674a045/src/lib/es2015.iterable.d.ts#L23

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Yes, is there any way to cast it to `string|undefined`.

Comment: Its just using the underlying javascript APIs so its going to be a string no matter what. You could cast it with `<string>` or `as string` or simply declare the variable as a string, ie `const s:string=...` though the `any` type won't prevent misuse. But this should work too `const s = [...set.values()][0]`, it will give a compiler error if you try to specify `const s : number =...` for example

Comment: I'm inclined to believe that this is a bug in TS. I opened an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53223

Comment: This is unfortunately not going to change, see [ms/TS#33353](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33353).  Apparently the "right" way to do this is to check `done` and only use `value` if `done` is `false`.  Something like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJAYlm) shows.  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?